# cakephp forum plugin admin panel issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I have installed the Forum plugin by Miles Johnson. It is working fine for the fronted but in the admin panel. I am getting "Not Installed" message in the forum plugin. I have attached the screenshot of my problem.[image]

Comment: Where's the programming question?

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in this tutorial and did the same http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/forum @MikeB